# He is the only/first player who has won GS twice

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-perfect, perfect-aspect

> 1. He **is** the *only* player who **has won** GS twice.
> 2. He **is** the *first* player who **has won** GS twice.

Are both sentences grammatically valid? If the tennis player is still active, can I use the present perfect tense in both instances?

Answer (score 1):

**"He is the only player who has won (a? the?) GS twice"** is grammatically correct. The second sentence should read as follows: **"He is the first player *to win* (a? the?) GS twice."** My uncertainty about adding an article (**"a" or "the"**) is based on my not knowing what a **"GS"** is.

Comment: It really is not possible to say " "He is the first player who has won GS twice." ? On the other hand I could say "He is the only player to win GS twice." GS = Grand Slam in tennis there are four GS tournaments during season and if you win them all in one seaon you achieve so called Grand Slam.

Comment: @Thomas- It would just sound a little odd to a native speaker. Also, in American English we would usually put an article (either a or the) before GS or Grand Slam, since it is a specific accomplishment and event. We would ask, for instance, "Did he win the Grand Slam?" And you would answer, "Yes! And he is the the only player to win the Grand Slam twice!"

Comment: I agree mostly, however I think you could equally say "He is the the only player to win **a** Grand Slam twice.".

Comment: Yes, and I should apologize for inadvertently writing "the the" when I intended to use just one "the" before "only" in the last sentence of my comment. I'm sorry if it made the matter more confusing. After a few minutes have passed, we cannot further edit our comments.