# He is the first player who has won this trophy

Tags: grammar

I am curious to know whether I can use present perfect in my example even though it has been e.g. one year since that happened and there are two, three more players who has already done/achieved the same.

- He is the first player who **has won** this trophy. ...or this one can be said only shortly after it happened?

I know that the most natural way to say this is: He is the first player **to win** this trophy. But here I am focused on the present perfect tense. Even though it may sound a bit unnatural - could I use present perfect shortly after it happened as well as  a few months, years since.....

Thank you!

Comment: Related question, [Present Perfect usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73666/present-perfect-usage).

Comment: 'He WAS the first player to WIN' or 'He IS the first player TO HAVE WON' sound better to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [He is the only/first player who has won GS twice](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292906/he-is-the-only-first-player-who-has-won-gs-twice)

Answer (score 1):

*"He **is** the first player who **has** won this trophy"* - only until such time as the trophy is next awarded.